# RTP Extension Headers over UDP

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I'm trying to send images with certain metadata over UDP using gstreamer. The *sender* process grabs images from camera, and sends them in the pipeline as `appsrc ! rtpvrawpay ! udpsink` (the full pipeline string below, in case it's important). And on the reciever side I use `udpsrc ! rtpvrawdepay ! appsink`.

In order to add metadata I put a probe on the Source Pad of `rtpvrawpay`, and to read - probe on Sink Pad of `rtpvrawdepay`. The problems I'm having so far:

1. The "source" probe receives `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER_LIST` data, while the "sink" probe - `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER`. I would expect that I will get the same data type on both sides of UDP, so why it's not?
2. I fail to read the `twobytes_header` that was added by the sender, it fails already when trying to `gst_rtp_buffer_map` the buffer in the probe. **UPDATE**: *succeeded to read the header on the receiver side, see the code below. Still would like to understand why I see Buffer List VS Buffer on the two probe locations*.

Will appreciate any insights, or maybe a better direction for sending metadata with image over UDP.

Sender pipeline: `appsrc ! videoconvert ! queue ! rtpvrawpay name=ToRTP ! queue ! udpsink host=192.168.42.49 port=5566 sync=false async=false`

Reciever pipeline: `udpsrc port=5566 caps="application/x-rtp, media=(string)video, sampling=(string)BGR, clock-rate=(int)90000, depth=(string)8, width=(string)640, height=(string)480, encoding-name=(string)RAW" ! rtpvrawdepay name=FromRTP ! queue ! videoconvert ! appsink`

**UPDATE**: The Code that worked for me:

Sender Code:

```
GstRTPBuffer rtp_buf = GST_RTP_BUFFER_INIT;
gst_rtp_buffer_map(*buffer, GST_MAP_READWRITE, &rtp_buf);
gst_rtp_buffer_add_extension_twobytes_header(&rtp_buf, 1, 1, myInfo->buf, sizeof(myInfo->buf));
gst_rtp_buffer_unmap(&rtp_buf);
```

Receiver Code:

```
GstRTPBuffer rtp_buf = GST_RTP_BUFFER_INIT;
GstBuffer* buf = GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_BUFFER(info);
gst_rtp_buffer_map(buf, GST_MAP_READ, &rtp_buf);
gpointer myInfoBuf = nullptr;
guint size         = 0;
gst_rtp_buffer_get_extension_twobytes_header(&rtp_buf, &appbits, 1, 0, &myInfoBuf, &size);
gst_rtp_buffer_unmap(&rtp_buf);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The "source" probe receives GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER_LIST data, while
> the "sink" probe - GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER. I would expect that I
> will get the same data type on both sides of UDP, so why it's not?

On the sender this depends on the type of data that passes through the RTP payloader: small packets (e.g. audio or small video frames) that fit in the MTU configuration of the payloader will trigger the `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` probe whereas packets exceeding the MTU will be split into a list of packets and trigger the `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER_LIST` probe.

On the receiver, your probe on the sink pad of the RTP depayloader always receives a single packet from the UDP source, in this case `GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BUFFER` is applicable.